# Update one table using data from another table - Oracle

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g, inner-join

Here is my trial query. I am trying to update `TABLE1` table with it's corresponding data from `ADDR` based on person_id. This below says missing SET keyword.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 CFI
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, ZIP FROM ADDR WHERE PERSON_ID = CFI.PERSON_ID AND STATUS = 'Active' 
) AS ADDR_DATA
SET CFI.PAYEE_ADDRESS1 = ADDR_DATA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
    CFI.PAYEE_ADDRESS2 = ADDR_DATA.ADDRESS_LINE2, 
    CFI.PAYEE_CITY= ADDR_DATA.CITY, 
    CFI.PAYEE_STATE_PROVINCE = ADDR_DATA.STATE_PROVINCE,
    CFI.PAYEE_POSTALCODE = ADDR_DATA.ZIP, 
    CFI.PAYEE_COUNTRY_CODE = 'USA'    
WHERE CFI.CUSTOMER_INSTITUTION_ID = 966362 AND CFI.PERSON_ID = ADDR_DATA.PERSON_ID;
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1
USING (
       SELECT PERSON_ID, 
              ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, ZIP 
         FROM ADDR 
        WHERE STATUS = 'Active' 
      ) ADDR_DATA
   ON TABLE1.PERSON_ID = ADDR_DATA.PERSON_ID 
      AND TABLE1.CUSTOMER_INSTITUTION_ID = 966362 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE
      SET PAYEE_ADDRESS1 = ADDR_DATA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
          PAYEE_ADDRESS2 = ADDR_DATA.ADDRESS_LINE2, 
          PAYEE_CITY = ADDR_DATA.CITY, 
          PAYEE_STATE_PROVINCE = ADDR_DATA.STATE_PROVINCE,
          PAYEE_POSTALCODE = ADDR_DATA.ZIP, 
          PAYEE_COUNTRY_CODE = 'USA';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it says missing ON keyword.

Comment: tried selecting `PERSON_ID` from ADDR_DATA subquery, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
UPDATE TABLE1 CFI
    SET (PAYEE_ADDRESS1, PAYEE_ADDRESS2, PAYEE_CITY, PAYEE_STATE_PROVINCE, PAYEE_POSTALCODE, PAYEE_COUNTRY_CODE) =
        (SELECT ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, ZIP, 'USA' FROM ADDR WHERE PERSON_ID = CFI.PERSON_ID AND STATUS = 'Active')
    WHERE CFI.CUSTOMER_INSTITUTION_ID = 966362;
```

EDIT: bug fixed (hopefully)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it says, `ADDR_DATA.PERSON_ID` invalid identifier.